# How to squash all commits and merge with master and push to GitHub

Tags: git, github

So, essentially I created a Git and GitHub repository for a LaTeX-project (thesis). I created a macro in TexStudio for automatically committing and pushing changes made. In the beginning I just committed and pushed everything to the local and remote *master* branch. As I use commit/push as a way to save small incremental changes, I created a new branch *apprentice* for this purpose, only merging with master after substantial changes has been made. However, when merging the entire commit history for apprentice were transferred to master. I did not desire this to happen.

So essentially I run the following code:

```
git add .
git commit "message"
git push origin apprentice

git checkout master
git merge apprentice
git push origin master
```

This obviously does not do what I want.

1. So, first of all I want need a way to "tidy up" local and remote *master* branch. At the current stage, I don't really need to trace any previous commits in master. I tried creating a "test" branch, there I ran `git rebase --interactive [first commit hash]`. However, running `git log` still lists all commits ever committed. How can I merge all commits in master into the last one both in local and remote master branch?
2. For future merging of commits from *apprentice* to *master*, I would like a way of doing this without transferring the entire commit history on `apprentice`. I am trying to find a way of tracking minor changes to my document, and at the same time being able to follow the more significant changes made, such additions of sections and paragraphs. Therefore, I want a way gather the changes made in `apprentice` (since the last commit to master) as one commit to `m̀aster` and be pushed to remote repo. I have tried illustrate below what I want.

```
master:     [1st commit]----------------------[big commit]--------------------[big commit]
                    \                            /                                /     
apprentice:          [commit]---[commit]-[commit]---[commit]---[commit]---[commit]---[commit]---
```

How can I best accomplish this? ..and is there a semi-automated way of doing it, like calling a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want `master` to be a history of milestones on `apprentice`. Something like;

```
*------------A-----------B (master)
 \            \           \
  a1--a2--a3---am--b1--b2--bm (apprentice)
```

This is a [common workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging-with-squash?view=azure-devops#what-is-a-squash-merge) when you want a simple linear history on `master` at the expense of losing some history from your *topic* branches.

Each time you want to update `master` you should;

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash apprentice
git commit
# edit your commit message as you see fit the details of your squashed 
# commits will be available to you as a default merge commit
git checkout apprentice
git merge --no-ff -X theirs master
```

The final line does a non fast-forward merge from `master` into `apprentice` and will resolve any conflicts with the changes from `master`. This merge is helpful because the next squash commit will attempt to squash everything from the last common ancestor. Without this merge your last common ancestor will always be `*` instead of `am`, `bm` and so on.

Comment: Yes, *"milestones"* is a good word for it. More to the point, I want to be able to open commits on `master` in GitHub and see the changes made from the previous *milestone* to the last. I'd prefer to keep the full history on `apprentice` if possible, but it is strictly not necessary. Can you elaborate on what the last line in your coding example does?

Comment: @pehkawn, I've expanded on why the last line is useful in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase --i` is definitely, what you can use. You can rebase head of local master onto itself, and squash all your commits into single one:

```
git checkout master
get rebase -i HEAD~<nuber of your commits>
```

It is important to understand the difference between `merge` and `rebase`. One of them is that you overwrite the git history. So you probably will have to do force push to the origin then.

Comment: I tried this on a test branch. Essentially I ran `git checkout -b test`, `git rebase --interactive [tag of first commit]`. This opened a list of all commits on the branch back to the first, closing it seemingly ran the process. However, running `git log`, the full commit history is seemingly still there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on what the differences between `merge` and `rebase` are?

Comment: @pehkawn On the second step you have to set `squash` or `s` instead of `pick` on proper commits. `rebase` puts your commits on the top of the git history, unlike merge which puts commits chronologically. Please see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: Merge is not *chronological*. It is *topological*. You are creating a graph—a directed, acyclic graph—of commits. The `git log` command linearizes this topologically twisty graph for display purposes. Use `git log --graph` to have `git log` draw a crude ASCII graph diagram.

Comment: (That aside, rebase probably is what the OP wants.)

Comment: @ArtemKhodos I ran `git rebase -i [first SHA]` on branch `test`, and substituted `pick` with `squash` (except the first one). However, I get "Merge conflict ..." error messages for some of the files. Any idea why this happen, and how I can resolve it? Btw, does `rebase` affect the other repos? When squashing `master`, I still want to retain the history in my development branch...

Comment: @torek Rebase seem to do what I want. Essentially, I want to tidy up the `master` branch. Right now is full of commits, each commit only representing very small changes to the document. Forward, I want to keep a development branch (`apprentice`) for small changes/additions to a chapter/section in my thesis, then when I have written a chapter/section, I want add all changes in this chapter to `master` as a single commit.

Comment: @pehkawn: your plan, of adding single commits to `master` that duplicate (but condense) the work from many commits on `apprentice`, is not a good one. This goes against the whole "directed acyclic graph" concept that allows Git to perform merging. Rebase is about *copying* commits, and the idea with rebase is that you will copy the commits to new-and-improved commits and *stop using the originals*. If you keep using the originals, you'll set yourself up for ever more painful merges, with more and more conflicts.

Comment: You must choose: do you want many small commits, or one big commit? Then you must go with your choice. Long-time Git users tend to recommend the many-small-commits method; I use a hybrid method myself, where I have many small commits, but sometimes copy-and-discard-originals (i.e., use `git rebase`) to make a new set of somewhat fewer, somewhat larger commits ... then merge that smaller set and proceed from there.

Comment: Note that when using a *real* merge—which may require overriding Git's attempt to do a *fast-forward* operation instead; see the `--no-ff` option—you can later tell `git log` to follow only the *main line* commits on `master`, using `git log --first-parent master`, so as not to see any of the small commits.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the thorough reply. Your second reply describes somewhat what I want to do. I've tried elaborating on this in the OP. The small commits method makes sense because I can easily revert minor changes to the text/editing if I'm not happy with them. At the same time it would make sense to easily track more larger, more meaningful changes such as additions of entire sections and paragraphs. (The idea was that I could share the project with my supervisor, so that it would be easy to track the more meaningful changes I make on `master`.)

Answer (score 1):

I have redrawn your pattern here, using uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs:

```
A------------F--------J   <-- master
 \          /        / 
  B--C--D--E--G--H--I--K   <-- apprentice
```

Note that the *branch names* are labels that point to (or attach to) *specific commits*.  Whenever you are on a branch and make a *new* commit, Git makes the new commit such that it points back to the old branch-tip, and then adjusts the branch *name* so that it points to the new commit, which is now the new branch-tip.  The fact that commits `A`, `F`, and `J` are "on" master is implied by the fact that by starting at merge commit `J` and working back to its first parent, you arrive at `F`, which is also a merge commit.  Working back to `F`'s first parent, you arrive at commit `A`.  Commit `A` is the very first commit ever so it has no parent at all, and the process stops.

The `git log` command will do this working-backwards for you.  You need `--first-parent` to prevent it from *also* working backwards from `J` to `I`.

The commands that *produce* this pattern are everyday Git.  The only special cases lie in creating `master` initially, then creating `apprentice` initially, and doing the *first* merge:

```
$ git init        # makes the new, empty repository
... create files and `git add` them all ...
$ git commit      # creates commit `A` and thereby allows the name `master` to exist
```

At this point you have:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
```

in your repository.  Then:

```
git checkout -b apprentice
```

results in:

```
A   <-- apprentice (HEAD), master
```

You can now create commit `B` in the usual way: edit files in your work-tree, `git add` them, and so on, and run `git commit`.  This produces commit `B` which causes the two branch names to point to different commits:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <-- apprentice (HEAD)
```

Note how commit `B` points back to existing commit `A`, and Git has put the new commit's hash ID into the name `apprentice`, to which the special name `HEAD` is attached.

You now create commits `C-D-E` in the same (ordinary, everyday) way:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B--C--D--E   <-- apprentice (HEAD)
```

To make commit `F`, you must `git checkout master`:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D--E   <-- apprentice
```

(note how you are now using commit `A` instead of commit `E`, and `HEAD` is now attached to `master`) and then `git merge apprentice`.  At this point, though, you *must* force Git not to take advantage of something Git spots instantly here.

The way `git merge` works is that it finds the *merge base* commit of your current commit, `A`, and your selected commit `E`.  That's the best *shared* commit, found by starting at `E` and working backwards, and starting at `A` and working backwards, at the same time.  But that's obviously commit `A` itself, which is not only shared, but also the *current* commit.  At this point, `git merge` will use a short-cut: it won't actually *merge* at all.  Instead, it will do a *fast-forward* operation, which is not a merge.  That would make the name `master` simply point directly to existing commit `E`, and check out commit `E`.  That is not what we want: we want to force Git to make actual merge commit `F`.

To do this, we run `git merge --no-ff apprentice`.  Git then compares the snapshot in `A`, the merge base commit, against the snapshot in `A`, the current commit.  This of course shows no changes at all.  Then Git compares the snapshot in `A` vs that in `E`.  Git now combines the two sets of changes—this *combining* is trivial of course–and applies the combined changes to the merge base snapshot in `A`, and makes our new merge commit `F`:

```
A------------F   <-- master (HEAD)
 \          /
  B--C--D--E   <-- apprentice
```

The *snapshot* in commit `F` matches that in commit `E`.  But `F` is a new, different commit, one with *two* parents: a merge commit.  Its two parents are `A` and `E`, in that order.

We can now `git checkout apprentice` and resume working.  After making three more commits, we have this:

```
A------------F   <-- master
 \          /
  B--C--D--E--G--H--I   <-- apprentice (HEAD)
```

We can now `git checkout master`, to move `HEAD` to `master` and select commit `F`, and then run `git merge apprentice`.  The `--no-ff` option is no longer required.  You may use it if you wish; it has no effect.  The *merge base* of `F` and `I` is commit `E`: one step back, along the second parent, from `F` reaches `E`, and three steps back, along the only parent available each time, from `I` reaches `E`.  Commit `E` is not commit `F`, so there is no chance for `git merge` to do a fast-forward instead of merging.

Git will now diff `E` vs `F` to see what "you" changed (nothing, again) and then diff `A` vs `I` to see what "they" changed (all of your changes to get to `I`).  The merge process then combines these—the nothing with the something—and applies the *combined* changes to the snapshot in the merge base `E`.  The result is of course the same as the snapshot in `I`, and Git makes new two-parent merge commit `J` to hold this snapshot and to point back to existing commits `F` and `I`:

```
A------------F--------J   <-- master (HEAD)
 \          /        /
  B--C--D--E--G--H--I   <-- apprentice
```

You can now `git checkout apprentice` and continue working.  At whatever point you like, you repeat the "switch to `master` and merge" to make a new major (merge) commit.  You switch back to `apprentice` to make new minor (everyday work) commits, and the pattern keeps growing.

In the next few drawings we can leave out the special name `HEAD` since we're just looking at the overall repository, rather than where you're going to make your next commit.  Over time, your repository continues to grow:

```
A------------F--------J   <-- master
 \          /        /
  B--C--D--E--G--H--I--K--L   <-- apprentice

A------------F--------J-----M   <-- master
 \          /        /     /
  B--C--D--E--G--H--I--K--L   <-- apprentice

A------------F--------J-----M   <-- master
 \          /        /     /
  B--C--D--E--G--H--I--K--L--N--O--P   <-- apprentice
```

The "stitching" pattern here means that if you follow *all* commits—as `git log` does by default–from the tip of `master`, you see everything, but if you follow only the *first-parent* links, as `git log --first-parent` does, you see only the major commits, each of which is a merge commit (and then at the end, the initial commit `A`).

Some people like to make a totally empty initial commit.  If you use GitHub, they rather encourage an initial commit whose contents are a `README` and/or `LICENSE` file, which is generally a good way to do things.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and detailed reply. I've been testing your solution over a couple of days, making regular small commits to `apprentice` then making a `merge --no-ff` with `master`. Both branches are then pushed to GitHub. Checking both branches on GitHub, I still find all the tiny commits on `apprentice` transferred to `master`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Commits are "on" (or "contained within") a branch if they are *reachable from* the tip of the branch. In the last diagram above, the name `master` points to commit `M`. Therefore commit `M` is on the branch, and `L` and `J` are on the branch (via `M`), and `K` (via `L`), and `I` (via both `J` and `K`), and so on. The pattern you wanted—as you showed in your post—puts commits that are on `apprentice` on `master` too.

Comment: To *view* only the *top line* commits, instead of `git log master`, you want `git log --first-parent master`. This directs `git log` to ignore the *second* parent of each merge—the down-and-left arrows coming out of each merge commit—and stick only with the directly-backwards-pointing arrows going from `M` to `J`, then `J` to `F`, and finally `F` to `A`.

Comment: One key item here, perhaps lost in the verbosity, is this: **Commits are quite often on *more than one branch*.**